# Redrawing Issues in Swift Observation framework

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I am creating a interface with SwiftUI.
Found that for the first version code, the Text on the page is updated synchronously when the content in the TextField is modified; however, for the second version, the Text is not updated synchronously, but is updated upon re-entry to the page (in other words modifying the textfield doesn't trigger redrawing).
I'm confuse about the second version not being able to update the text on the page.

```
// Version 1
@Bindable var palette: Palette

Text(palette.name)
TextField("name", text: $palette.name)
```

```
// Version 2
@Bindable var store: PaletteStore
var index: Int

Text(store.palettes[index].name)
TextField("name", text: $store.palettes[index].name)
```

These are my models:

```
// Palette
@Observable class Palette {
    var name: String
    ...
}
```

```
// PaletteStore
@Observable class PaletteStore {
    var palettes: [Palette]
    ...
}
```

I've tried to find information about Observation on the internet, but there's just so little of it

### Update

Thanks to all the replies, I finally found out why. In my original code, palettes is a computed property and does not use any storage properties. Therefore his modifications are not tracked in the Observation mechanism. I found a way to manually trigger a redrawing in the computed property in the WWDC demo: https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2023/10149

```
@Observable class Donut {
  var name: String {
    get {
      access(keyPath: \.name)
      return someNonObservableLocation.name 
    }
    set {
      withMutation(keyPath: \.name) {
        someNonObservableLocation.name = newValue
      }
    }
  } 
}
```

Comment: The second version is unsafe you should use index

Comment: @lorem ipsum
, you forgot the **not**

Comment: @workingdogsupportUkraine you are right, my spell check is horrible lately. Index should NOT be used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is some test code that shows how to update the `Text` as you type into
the `TextField` using the Observation framework with your second version code. Using MacOS 14.1, with Xcode 15, tested on real ios 17 devices (not Previews), and macCatalyst.

```
@Observable class Palette {
    var name: String
    
    init(name: String) {
        self.name = name
    }
}

@Observable class PaletteStore {
    var palettes: [Palette]

    init(palettes: [Palette]) {
        self.palettes = palettes
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    var store = PaletteStore(palettes: [Palette(name: "name-0"), Palette(name: "name-1")])
    var index: Int = 0

    var body: some View {
        NextView(store: store, index: index)
    }
}

struct NextView: View {
    @Bindable var store: PaletteStore
    var index: Int

    var body: some View {
        Text(store.palettes[index].name)
        TextField("name", text: $store.palettes[index].name).border(.red)
    }
}
```

Note that Version 1 of your code is a better option.